# "The coordinates or measures are out of bounds" when converting labels to annotations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, labeling, annotation

Am converting Labels to Annotations in ArcMap 10.1. However an error messages pops up with this message.

The coordinates or measures are out of bounds. Text = RUSHOZI

The coordinates or measures are out of bounds. Text = KIGAAGA

The coordinates or measures are out of bounds. Text = KAMUKUZI

Has anyone experienced this? How did you resolve this problem.

Please share the steps taken.

Answer (score 3):

See the Esri help file under [coordinates or measures are out of bounds](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/12602), which explains:

> A coordinate of the added feature is beyond the extents of the feature
>   class x,y domain. Geodatabase feature coordinates must fall within the
>   feature class x,y domain extent. The x,y domain is set when the
>   dataset or stand-alone feature class is created. It cannot be updated
>   after creation.

The help file lists the steps to resolve this issue.

Comment: you should create a new dataset with extended bounds, details of how to do it? see 
 https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008530

Answer (score 0):

As none of the causes or solutions listed under the [Esri help](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012800) posted by Stephen Lead applied in my case. I identified that the method of Horizontal Alignment can cause the error.

If I use an X Offset and Full as Horizontal Alignment for the lables, none of the lables can be converted to Annotation. Using the X Offset but changing the Horizontal Alignment to Center, all lables were converted to Annotation without the error.

[image]

(ArcMap 10.2.2)